# Have a value centered inside a Kendo Radial Gauge

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I'm trying to create a Kendo UI radial gauge, but instead of having a pointer (needle) with the current value, I'd like to have the the text centered inside the gauge itself

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonscript/meL07z4o/) of my empty Gauge.

I've hidden all the non-essential parts of the Gauge and I'm using the range property to show the value of the gauge

I'd like to be able to display the value in the middle of the gauge itself

[image: Clean Gauge]

Here's my current Gauge definition (from the jsFiddle):

```
 $("#gauge").kendoRadialGauge({
     pointer: [],
     scale: {
         minorUnit: 5,
         startAngle: -30,
         endAngle: 210,
         max: 100,
         labels: { visible: false },
         majorTicks: { visible: false },
         minorTicks: { visible: false },
         ranges: [{
             from: 0,
             to: 40,
             color: "#008000"
         }, {
             from: 40,
             to: 60,
             color: "#E29F30"
         }]
     },
 });
```

For bonus points, if you know how to change the thickness of the gauge that would be appreciated too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either draw directly on the SVG canvas using plain script, the KendoUI drawinf library, or 3rd party library like D3.

Or you can simply position an HTML element with the text in the center with some CSS:

```
<div id="gauge-container">
    <div id="gauge"></div>
    <div id="val" class="gaugeVal"></div>
</div>

.gaugeVal {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 42px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: -100px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #555;
}

$("#val").text("64%");
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/meL07z4o/1/)**

Comment: Thanks! I went the route of CSS. It doesn't seem that modifying the SVG output is as supported by Kendo